# Nodejs : How to avoid async call in nodejs inside loop?

Tags: node.js, async-await

Here I need to fetch the data from database twice and return the result as response.

But my problem is before fetching the data from database the response function is called and it will return the empty response

Here my code is:

```
Stages.findById(comp.currentStage.stage, function(stgErr, stageName) {

    if (stgErr) {
        res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, usrErr);
        return;
    }

    comp.currentStageName = stageName.name;
    components.push(comp);

    ServiceProviderUser.findById(comp.currentStage.user, function(
      usrErr,
      userName
    ) {
        if (usrErr) {
            res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, usrErr);
            return;
        }
        comp.personResponsible = userName.firstName + " " + userName.lastName;
        components.push(comp);
        console.log("1111111111", comp);
    });

    checkCondition(); //check condition is the function for response send
});

function checkCondition() {
    res.json(HttpStatus.OK, components);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your return function call in callback of send database call

```
Stages.findById(comp.currentStage.stage, function (stgErr, stageName){
        if (stgErr) {
            res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, usrErr);
            return;
        }
        comp.currentStageName = stageName.name;
        components.push(comp);
        ServiceProviderUser.findById(comp.currentStage.user, function (usrErr, userName){
            if (usrErr) {
                res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, usrErr);
                return;
            }
            comp.personResponsible = userName.firstName+ ' '+userName.lastName;
            components.push(comp);
            console.log("1111111111",comp);

            checkCondition() //moved in callback of this DB call
        })       

})

function checkCondition() {
    res.json(HttpStatus.OK, components);
}
```

This is however not a good approach. You can use "Promises" for better handling of async code.
I found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) as best explanation of promises. Hope it helps !!